# How to access the value of a cookie injected in the request header on a POST call using Lua?

Tags: cookies, lua, httprequest, httpcookie

I'm attempting to retrieve an authentication cookie from a POST sign-in request.  When I send this request using Postman, I see the cookie's value in the Cookies tab of the response in Postman.

[Postman Response Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnq2Y.png)

My current Lua script is as follows:

```
local signInUrl = webBaseUrl.."/signin"
local signInResponse = http.request({"POST", signInUrl, headers={
    ["Content-Type"]="application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    ["Referer"] = baseUrl}, data="UrlHash=&UserName="..username.."&Password=123&RememberMe=false", auto_decompress=true})
for i,v in pairs(signInResponse.cookies) do print(i,v) end
```

Printing out the value of the cookies returns a sessionId cookie and a return email cookie, but not the authentication cookie that I'm looking for.

I can see that the authentication cookie that I'm looking for is actually located in the Request Headers, in the Postman Console.

[Postman Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn2Mp.png)

How would I go about getting the value of this cookie?